# Textarea very strange behavior

Tags: css, html

Please, have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/g995s/.

```
<div id="textarea_wrapper">
  <textarea>How and where my width is derived from?</textarea>
</div>


#textarea_wrapper{
height: 250px;
border:thick solid green;
}
textarea{
background-color: #930;     
border:none;
margin:0;
width:auto;
resize:none;
    overflow:hidden;
height:95%;
    padding-top:5%;
}
```

It is impossible to me to explain two things: The first one is why textarea goes outside its parent since height+padding-top=100%?
The second one is how and from where this certain width of textarea is derived?

Thank you

Comment: try `width:100%` on your textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding-top percentage is based of the **width** of the parent element, not the height.

So it goes outside because 95% of the smaller height + 5% of the larger width = more than 100% of the height.

The width is the default width for the textarea because setting `width: auto` on textareas does nothing.

Set the textarea width and height to 100% and use a fixed measurement like `px` or `em` for the padding if you don't like how the top and bottom percentages work.

Then use `box-sizing: border-box` on the textarea to make its width, height and padding stay within 100% of its parent; http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 5):

In regards to the first issue, the percentage based `padding-top` value is relative to the width, not the height, therefore the positioning won't be consistent if the width of the browser is changed - try resizing the window to see this.

> [**8 Box model - 8.4 Padding properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties)
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Its the `padding-top` that is increasing the size of the text area

*edit: beaten to it! :)